# Salvar o total de linhas de um SELECT com WHERE em uma variável

Tags: select

Preciso desenvolver um código onde o total de linha de um SELECT seja armazenado em uma variável. Escrevi o código abaixo, mas quando utilizo o WHERE retorna um erro *"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in"*.

É possível fazer um SELECT utilizando um WHERE e salvar o total de registros localizados em uma váriável com o formato "0000"?

```
include "conecta_mysql.inc";

$escritorio = $_POST["n_escritorio"];

$resultado = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM registros WHERE escritorio=$escritorio");
$linhas = $resultado->num_rows;

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: O resultado retornado é inteiro. Se você quer formatar o resultado, verifique quantas casas tem esse número e complete com zeros a esquerda para formar 4 dígitos.

Comment: Jefferson, boa tarde! Nesse caso devo utilizar um switch case para checar a quantidade de digitos e completar concatenando com 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado a todos pela a ajuda. Uma pessoa me ajudou com a seguinte solução:

```
$escritorio = $_POST["n_escritorio"];

echo "$escritorio<br>";

$resultado = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM registros WHERE escritorio = '".utf8_decode($escritorio)."'");
$resultado->execute();
$resultado->store_result();

$linhas = $resultado->num_rows;
echo "total: $linhas";

$mysqli->close();
```